# How to prevent Sub Reports can grow no affect the Page Number - Crystal Report VB

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My report has multiple subreports, each with their own section.

The report's Page Number displays correctly if the 3 subreports are small; but when a subreport is split onto two pages, the 1st page number doesn't appear - only the second one. It seems to me that the subreports overlap with the page number.

I tried putting the page number in other sections (the footer) and the result is the same. How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: Can you please specify in which section(s) you have put your subreports? By footer, do you mean the group-, page- or report-footer? A page footer should be visible on every page.

Comment: i can't add any image cuz i'm don't have enoughts points. By the way, the page number is on page footer section and for this I was asking for help. The rest of my subreports are in report header (diferents report header's sections for each one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your subreports into a group or detail section.

A page footer will only be printed if the report header is finished.